# Error on adding action to UIButton with selector

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, selector

I'm trying to add an event to a UIbutton:

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aa.png"] 
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn addTarget:self 
     action:@selector(Presed:)];
```

and I'm getting this warning :

```
"UIButtom may not respond to addTarget:action"
```

The interface I'm creating this button for inherits from `CDVPlugin`

what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling a method that is not declared.
it should be.

[– addTarget:action:forControlEvents:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a)

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Presed:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: `-addTarget:action:`  that is the method you tried to call first. that method is not declared anywhere.